# QGIS Model Designer - Use name of selected Polygon in Output layer

Tags: qgis, modelbuilder, clip

I am building a simple model using QGIS Model Designer.
Coming from ESRI, I am having a little trouble.

I am clipping buildings of a city by overlaying and iterating over the districts.
The name of the various output files should be like "buildings_[districtName]".

So I need to get the name of the current overlying district from attribute table.

So far, I wasn't succesful. Do you have any advise, how to do it?[image]

Comment: Output layer names are set when your run the model.

Comment: I know, but how would I set the output layer name to a variable, that depends on the currently selected field in attribute table?